# Detect Volume Up/Down in Sleep mode

Tags: android, android-broadcast

[Possibly duplicate] But I didnt find any answers to this particular question. The work arounds not working exactly.

I am trying to detect volume up/down when the phone is in sleep mode. I tried the following mentioned in the below site,

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html

but the receiver gets invoked when the phone is unlocked, not when the phone is in sleep mode.

Please help me how to detect the volume up/down when its in sleep mode.

I been struggling for hours to implement this functionality

Comment: the phone sleeps. you don't want to wake it up.

Comment: I wanted to perform some actions based on the key press events